# keras model produces results different with what I intended

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

My model is as below:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, 'relu', input_shape = (1,)))
model.add(Dense(6, 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, 'linear'))
```

I want to make my model to get [10,5] regardless of the input.

So I customized the loss as:

```
def custom_loss1(y_true,y_pred):
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(10-y_pred[0]))+ tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(5-y_pred[1]))
```

I used data as
input = (random num) / output = (random num)

I intended the model to get a result as (10,5) regardless of input.

However, the model does not learn anything.

What is the problem??

Comment: Not for sure, but maybe `y_pred[0]` refers to the 1st row, instead of 1st column?

Comment: What makes you think this code produces (10,5) predictions? Your last layer is size (2,)

Comment: After training, the model output is like (7.48, 7.50). So I changed the loss's value from (10, 5) to (40, 20), then the model output is like (29.8, 29.9). I think it goes to the average.

Comment: @KotaMori It solved! The problem was as what you said.

Comment: @asaf92 I mean [10,5], the value of output not the output shape. I edited, thank you.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad :) Can you show us the code where you compile/run/fit the model?